# Can't Remote Manage Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019

Hyper-V installed on my Server 2019 machine. I have a VM setup on it without a problem. I have my admin account in the Server Administrators and the Hyper-V administrators group. Hyper V Service is running. On my Windows 11 and my Windows 10 machines I run Hyper V console as admin and  I go to connect to server and connect with the same account. It gives me the message:

> An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "SERVER01".
> Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that
> you are authorized to connect to the server.
>
> You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator
> of the authorization policy for the computer "SERVER01".

I can remote desktop to the server but for some reason it won't let me connect to the HyperV console. I have also run the Enable-PSRemoting command and that did not change anything. What am I missing?

**UPDATE** Reinstalled Hyper V and still not change. There are no security logs showing I am bumping up against a permission issue as well.

Comment: Funny, it stopped working for us after one of the upgrades, not sure which one, maybe after 2012 -> 2012R2, but more likely after upgrading to 2016. Never figured it out, so I'm curious where this will go :D

Comment: @bviktor funny because it is working on my other 2 servers. But this recently built one from the ground up patched to the latest is giving us a problem.